# SFW SQL QUERY Ambiguous field

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I am trying to run a query that references 3 tables and return a field from one table. I am receiving an error saying ambiguous field even though i have tried to identify columns tables. I'm not sure with the whole code yet, because i can't get past the ambiguous error to test what i have so far.

Edit: Column 'supplier_id' in field list is ambiguous is the error i am receiving

```
Select supplier_id, company_name, country, sales_contact_name, email
FROM SUPPLIER, COFFEE, COFFEE_SHOP
Where SUPPLIER.supplier_id = COFFEE.supplier_id 
and COFFEE.shop_id=COFFEE_SHOP.shop_id 
and COFFEE_SHOP.city = "XXX";
```

Comment: first of all I would suggest to rewrite your query to the modern JOIN-syntax. After that provide aliases to your select columns

Comment: You need to use `tablename.columnname` in the `SELECT` list, not just `WHERE`.

Comment: Please, always show us the COMPLETE error message

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh I've been trying to get my boss to switch for a decade....

Comment: @Barmar, old habits die hard. It's easier to reach the newcomers. (My boss is still doing implicit joins too...)

Comment: @Barmer Only one decade? They been obsolete for **three** now :D

Answer (score 0):

In short, the output by default is ALL columns from 3 tables. When we specify the output column, if the same column name exists in more than one input tables, we need to explicitly tell query engine in [table_alias].[column_name] format.

Depend on your DB engine, the provided query will generate a product join, which is very resource consuming and in-efficient.

You can rewrite the query as below:

```
SELECT 
    SUPPLIER.supplier_id, 
    company_name, 
    country, 
    sales_contact_name, 
    email
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN COFFEE
ON SUPPLIER.supplier_id = COFFEE.supplier_id
JOIN
COFFEE_SHOP
ON
COFFEE.shop_id=COFFEE_SHOP.shop_id 
and COFFEE_SHOP.city = "XXX"
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice and input. We are using outdated material i guess. code makes a little more sense wrote this way. I could have done a simple where query, but wanted to challenge myself then couldn't figure out why the ambiguous error when I was identifying the tables.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to always writing out your joins, you should also always use aliases for your tables or views on any query complicated enough to involve a join.

```
SELECT s.supplier_id, company_name, country, sales_contact_name, email
FROM SUPPLIER s
INNER JOIN COFFEE c ON c.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
INNER JOIN COFFEE_SHOP cs ON cs.shop_id = c.shop_id
WHERE cs.city = 'XXX';
```

Also, the SQL language likes single quotes rather than double quotes for string literals, and though not all databases follow this the ANSI standard actually reserves doubles quotes for object names. This means as originally written the `"XXX"` literal was likey to be interpreted as the name of a table or view instead of a string value.